# how to check if image is nil then load default image Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image

i am loading an image from a url - the son is added to a dictionary and then an array is created with the image and a UIImageView uses that image. This works fine as long as the url contains an image. I know i need to check for nil and load a default image if so but i can't seem to get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSString *string = _baseUrlString2;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
// 2
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
    // 3
    NSDictionary *dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
    //NSLog(@" name %@", [dic objectForKey:@"name"]);
    //NSLog(@" image %@", [dic objectForKey:@"images"]);
    //NSLog(@" barcode %@", [dic objectForKey:@"barcode"]);

    _data.text = [dic objectForKey:@"barcode"];
    _data2.text = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
```

this is where the issue is - i added a break and noted that the array contained 0 objects so i tried to make this trigger the default image but it doesn't.  i also tried == nil

```
NSArray *picImage = [dic objectForKey:@"images"];

    if ([picImage isEqual:@"0 objects"]) {
        //yourImageURL is not valid
        _imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }
    else{

        //yourImageURL is valid
        NSString *image = [picImage objectAtIndex:0];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: image];
        _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url ]];                       
    }
```

this is the working code but crashes if image is missing

```
            /*
    NSArray *picImage = [dic objectForKey:@"images"];
    NSString *image = [picImage objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: image];
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url ]];
    */          
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing against its `NSLog` output, which is a little weird..

Replace:

```
if ([picImage isEqual:@"0 objects"])
```

With:

```
if ([picImage count] == 0)
```

Comment: thanks - that worked!  I'm new to this so i guess i may be going about it wrong.  What would be the preferred method?  Any direction is appreciated!